# Regex to check if a number is even

Tags: java, regex

Can we have a regex to detect if a number is even ?

I was wondering if we can have a regex to do this instead of usual `%` or bit operations.

Thanks for replies :)

Comment: Regexes operate on strings, but evenness is a property of numbers. What format are your numbers potentially in, in string format?

Comment: Please: only wonder about this, DON'T do it. Primitive integral types (byte, short, int and long) are made for storing numbers. BigInteger is made for storing really big numbers. Strings are for storing strings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the correct answer has already been given, I'll argue that regex would not be my first choice for this.

- if the number fits the `long` range, use `%`
- if it does not, you can use [`BigInteger.remainder(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#remainder%28java.math.BigInteger%29), but perhaps checking whether the last `char` represents an even digit would be more efficient.

Comment: Another trick is to check the rightmost digit is 0 or 1 which will be : (n & 1) == 1. True means odd, otherwise even

Answer (score 57):

You can try:

```
^-?\d*[02468]$
```

Explanation:

- `^` : Start anchor.
- `-?` : Optional negative sign.
- `\d*` : Zero or more digits.
- `[02468]` : Char class to match a 0
  or 2 or 4 or 6 or 8
- `$` : End anchor

Comment: fastest and with explanation. kudos.

Comment: Nice that you did not forget the negative values.;)

Answer (score 3):

If it is a string, just check if [`endsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))`(0) || endsWith(2) || ..` returns true. If it is number, it is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just check if the last number is a `0/2/4/6/8`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm not sure if it's the same syntax in java:

```
^\d*(2|4|6|8|0)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use regex for a job that can be easily done otherwise.

I came across this Microsoft blog that says the same: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140416032454/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bclteam/archive/2005/02/21/377575.aspx)

Comment: Can you elaborate what is in the link or why not use a regex in this instance?